# Non-numeric Argument to Binary Operator Error in R

Tags: r

The issue I believe is how CurrentDay is entered. It was previously created as:

```
Transaction <- function(PnL, Day)
  results <- list(a = PnL, b = Day)
  return(results)
```

Both PnL and Day are numeric values.

```
Day <- Transaction(PnL, Day)["b"]
```

Where Transaction returned a list and b is an integer.

```
moving_avg <- function(StockData, MA, CurrentDay){
  #MA = Days long the MA is
  #CurrentDay = What day we are currently on
  MAValue <- NULL
  total <- 0
  start <- CurrentDay - MA
  for(i in 1:length(MA)) {
    total <- total + StockData[[start, 4]]
    start <- start + 1
  }
  MAValue <- total/MA
  return(MAValue)
}
```

Anyone know why I am receiving this error?

> Error in CurrentDay - MA : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Please include sample data and show exactly how you are calling the function. See [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: The function's ok, you probably called it with non-numeric argument. Please provide a reproducible sample, like @MrFlick said.

Comment: I think I found the issue, CurrentDay is being imputed from a variable I designated from a list. When I just print CurrentDay I get $b [1] 41

Answer (score 86):

Because your question is phrased regarding your error message and not whatever your function is trying to accomplish, I will address the error.

`-`  is the 'binary operator' your error is referencing, and either `CurrentDay` or `MA` (or both) are non-numeric.

A binary operation is a calculation that takes two values (operands) and produces another value ([see wikipedia for more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_operation)). `+` is one such operator: "1 + 1" takes two operands (1 and 1) and produces another value (2). Note that the produced value isn't necessarily different from the operands (e.g., 1 + 0 = 1).

R only knows how to apply `+` (and other binary operators, such as `-`) to numeric arguments:

```
> 1 + 1
[1] 2
> 1 + 'one'
Error in 1 + "one" : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

When you see that error message, it means that you are (or the function you're calling is) trying to perform a binary operation with something that isn't a number.

**EDIT:**

Your error lies in the use of `[` instead of `[[`. Because `Day` is a list, subsetting with `[` will return a list, not a numeric vector. `[[`, however, returns an object of the class of the item contained in the list:

```
> Day <- Transaction(1, 2)["b"]
> class(Day)
[1] "list"
> Day + 1
Error in Day + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator

> Day2 <- Transaction(1, 2)[["b"]]
> class(Day2)
[1] "numeric"
> Day2 + 1
[1] 3
```

`Transaction`, as you've defined it, returns a list of two vectors. Above, `Day` is a list contain one vector. `Day2`, however, is simply a vector.

Comment: looking at my code, is my Day variable not a numeric value based on how it is originally set at the beginning? If not, what must I do to make it one?

Comment: I have a similar problem, only I’m getting it when trying to join to plots (a boxplot and a jitterplot) that run fine separately. My error message reads ‘Error in p + o : non-numeric argument to binary operator’. Should I create a separate question for this, or is this something that should be discussed here in the comments?

Comment: @CannedMan this is largely unrelated but easy to fix. If you are trying to put them next to each other use `par(mfrow = c(1,2)` or `par(mfrow = c(2,1)`. Else call the first plot and then use `points()` or the like

Comment: "R only knows how to apply + (and other binary operators, such as -) to numeric arguments" - tiny caveat: except in ggplot (& ggmap etc) pipes, where "+" is used like the %>% pipe.

Comment: @dez93_2000 true!

Answer (score 1):

If you run this before your code, everything is gonna be OK.

```
'+' <- function(e1, e2) {
  if (is.character(e1) | is.character(e2)) {
    paste0(e1, e2)
  } else {
    base::`+`(e1, e2)
  }
}
```