# Error in numInClass[i]%/%k : non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, machine-learning, modeling, r-caret

I cannot thrive to train a model with the `caret` package without errors.

Here is a minimum reproductible data set: [Dataset](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=36193914216851032970)

And here is the code I'm using...

```
data <- read.csv('file.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ',')

library(caret)
data <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
data$donation <- as.factor(data$donation)

set.seed(1337)
ctrl <- trainControl(
  method="repeatedcv",
  number="10",
  repeats=10)

data <- data[,-2]
nnet.fit <- train(donation ~ ., data = data,
                  method = "nnet",
                  trControl = ctrl,
                  verbose = FALSE,
                  tuneLength = 5)
```

...that leads to this error:

> Error in numInClass[i]%/%k : non-numeric argument to binary operator

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665740/4241464) but didn't understand how to solve my problem with it.

Any clue ?

Comment: In your definition of `ctrl`, I think that `number` should be numeric. At least, if I remove the quotes, I can run the code.

Comment: Thanks Stibu. So bad for such a typo :/

Answer (score 1):

Just seen this while trying to find a solution on the same. It's a very simple answer bro:
ctrl <- trainControl(
  method="repeatedcv",
  number="10",# Here the 10 should not be wrapped in quotation marks as its numeric
  repeats=10)