# colvar in scatter3D return error " clim[2] - clim[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Tags: scatter3d

Hallo again dear forum,

I am not the best of friends with these 3D plots, and I struggle with simple formatting stuff. Like now, where I can't color my plots from a variable.

```
with(samples3d, {
  s3d <- scatter3D(MDS2, MDS3, MDS1, pch = ifelse(meta$op.closed=="cl",22,21), type = "h",colvar = pcolor, lty.hplot=2, scale.y=0.75)
 } )
```

It gives me this error:

```
Error in clim[2] - clim[1] : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I can read from the documentation that:

> "colvar   :The variable used for coloring. ... if
>   specified, it should be a vector of equal length as (x, y, z)."

So in my naïve approach I checked

```
colvec <- as.vector(samples3d$pcolor)
MDS1vec <- as.vector(samples3d$MDS1)
length(MDS1vec)
43
length(colvec)
43
```

- and they are the same length, so what is wrong here?

Best,
Mathilde

Answer (score 2):

I also find the colouring scheme a bit difficult. But colvar should be a numeric vector, 1,2,3,4 up to number of groups you have. And then you have to supply col as another vector - having the length of *the amount of groups*. Scatter3D will then look up each of your numbers in that other vector, supplied as the argument 'col'. E.g.:

```
colvar <- as.numeric(as.factor(pcolor))
```

Now all your colours are made into numbers. And then:

```
col <-levels(as.factor(pcolor))
```

That's the col argument where the function can get the colours.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what kind of data is in your vectors, I would assume from the error message that your pcolor vector is non-numeric.

A detailed answer to this error message is given here:
[Non-numeric Argument to Binary Operator Error in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665428/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-error-in-r)

A solution could be to code your groups in pcolor with numeric values. At least that worked for me, when I had this problem.