# Error Multiply all rows by rows

Tags: r

I have facing an error recently, i have a data frame called Centroid like this( this is a small piece of the real archive)

```
      X1989  X1990  X1991       LAT            LON
   1     10    11    10   -44,3517712669 -22,9847296224
   2  12040 12040 14589   -42,2932250108 -22,7536045078
   3      3     3     3   -43,9128279672 -22,4248877183
   4     20    20    20   -44,2046056169 -22,4533649489
```

And i need to multiply each year column by the `LAT` column and `LON` column as well.

I tried doing that with a for loop

```
LAT<- Centroid[,29]
xlat<-as.list
for ( col in Centroid[,1:28]) {
  xlat<- col * Centroid[,29]
  cbind(TABTRUE,xlat, make.col.names= TRUE)

}
```

but I get this error:

> Error in col * Centroid[, 29] : non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Comment: I'm guessing by the commas in the LAT and LON values that those columns are of type character, not numeric. What does `class(Centroid$LAT)` say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/29665428/3358272

Comment: when i tipe
     class(Centroid$LAT)
 it returns: character.
i havent tought about that comma thing....

Comment: i also changed all the commas `.` with a `.`, before adding it to the dataframe, but the result of `class(Centroid$LAT)` is still `character` :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good candidate where `dplyr::mutate_at` can help. There is no need for a `for-loop` either.

Clearly data in `LAT` and `LON` columns contains comma `,` and those are non-numeric columns.

Now, first use `mutate_at` to convert `LAT` and `LON` columns to `numeric` (after replacing `,` with `.` ) and then use `mutate_at` again to multiply columns with year by `LAT`.

```
library(dplyr)

Centroid %>% mutate_at(vars(c("LAT","LON")),funs(as.numeric(gsub(",","\\.",.)))) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("X")),funs(.*LAT))

#          X1989        X1990        X1991       LAT       LON
# 1    -443.5177    -487.8695    -443.5177 -44.35177 -22.98473
# 2 -509210.4291 -509210.4291 -617015.8597 -42.29323 -22.75360
# 3    -131.7385    -131.7385    -131.7385 -43.91283 -22.42489
# 4    -884.0921    -884.0921    -884.0921 -44.20461 -22.45336
```

**Data:**

```
Centroid <- read.table(text =
"X1989  X1990  X1991       LAT            LON
1     10    11    10   -44,3517712669 -22,9847296224
2  12040 12040 14589   -42,2932250108 -22,7536045078
3      3     3     3   -43,9128279672 -22,4248877183
4     20    20    20   -44,2046056169 -22,4533649489",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: it does work!  thats great.
im kinda new to R and im not intimate with the dplyr.
but i will learn! thanks bro