# What syntax error is causing this specific error message?

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I am uisng `R` in `RStudio` and I have an `R` script which performs web scraping. I am stuck with an error message when running these specific lines:

```
      review<-ta1 %>%
              html_node("body") %>%
              xml_find_all("//div[contains@class,'location-review-review']")
```

The error message is as follows:

```
xmlXPathEval: evaluation failed
Error in `*tmp*` - review : non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In xpath_search(x$node, x$doc, xpath = xpath, nsMap = ns, num_results = Inf) :
  Invalid predicate [1206]
```

Note: I have `dplyr` and `rvest` libraries loaded in my `R` script.

I had a look at the answers to the following question on `StackOverflow`: 
[Non-numeric Argument to Binary Operator Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665428/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-error-in-r)

I have a feeling my solution relates to the answer provided by **Richard Border** to the question linked above. However, I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to correct my `R` syntax based on that answer.

Thank you for looking into my question.

Sample of ta1 added:

```
{xml_document}
<html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">\n<link rel="icon" id="favicon"  ...
[2] <body class="rebrand_2017 desktop_web Hotel_Review  js_logging" id="BODY_BLOCK_JQUERY_REFLOW" data-tab="TAB ...
```

Comment: Could you please add a sample of `ta1`?

Comment: @NelsonGon ta1 sample added

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example instead? Something like `ta1=...` which would throw this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to make a few assumptions here, since your post doesn't contain enough information to generate a reproducible example.

First, I'm guessing that you are trying to scrape TripAdvisor, since the id and class fields match for that site and since your variable is called `ta1`.

Secondly, I'm assuming that you are trying to get the text of each review and the number of stars for each, since that is the relevant scrape-able information in each of the classes you appear to be looking for.

I'll need to start by getting my own version of the `ta1` variable, since that wasn't reproducible from your edited version.

```r
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(magrittr)
library(tibble)

"https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/"                          %>% 
paste0("Hotel_Review-g186534-d192422-Reviews-")           %>%
paste0("Glasgow_Marriott_Hotel-Glasgow_Scotland.html") -> url

ta1 <- url %>% GET %>% read_html
```

Now write the correct xpaths for the data of interest

```r
# xpath for elements whose text contains reviews
xpath1 <- "//div[contains(@class, 'location-review-review-list-parts-Expand')]"

# xpath for the elements whose class indicate the ratings
xpath2 <- "//div[contains(@class, 'location-review-review-')]"
xpath3 <- "/span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating bubble_')]"
```

We can get the text of the reviews like this:

```r
ta1                                             %>% 
xml_find_all(xpath1)                            %>% # run first query
html_text()                                     %>% # extract text
extract(!equals(., "Read more")) -> reviews         # remove "blank" reviews
```

And the associated star ratings like this:

```r
ta1 %>% 
xml_find_all(paste0(xpath2, xpath3)) %>% 
xml_attr("class")                    %>% 
strsplit("_")                        %>%
lapply(function(x) x[length(x)])     %>% 
as.numeric                           %>% 
divide_by(10)                         -> stars
```

And our result looks like this:

```r
tibble(rating = stars, review = reviews)
## A tibble: 5 x 2
#  rating review                                                                                             
#   <dbl> <chr>                                                                                              
#1      1 7 of us attended the Christmas Party on Satu~
#2      4 "We stayed 2 nights over last weekend to att~
#3      3 Had a good stay, but had no provision to kee~
#4      3 Booked an overnight for a Christmas shopping~
#5      4 Attended a charity lunch here on Friday and ~
```

Comment: You are a genius! Exactly what I am doing. You made my day! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried to convert that tibble into a data frame as follows:
tibble1<-tibble(rating = stars, review = reviews)
df1<-as.data.frame(tibble1)
However, df1 is just showing a table with numbers. Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: @user3115933 Are you sure this isn't just because of how dataframes are displayed in the console? What happens if you try `df1$review` or `df$review[1]`?