# non-numeric argument to binary operator in dist function

Tags: r

I get the error for this code:

```
dist_matrix_euc <- dist(movies[,2:16], method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
```

Dataset "movies" has only numeric values (except names of columns). Full version of the error:
"**Error in 0 + x : non-numeric argument to binary operator**". Also i attach the screen of my dataset.[movies dataset segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z36v4.png)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665428/non-numeric-argument-to-binary-operator-error-in-r) could be useful.

Comment: i tried this option, but didnt help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include a reproducible question as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example include your data (as a dataframe object or use dput("yourdata"), the code you have tried and your expected output. This will make it more likely to get a good answer.

Comment: @Getrix2020 This error usually caused variation in data types. You can check datatypes using str command: str(movies)  or  sapply(movies,class)