# Non numeric argumento error in plot(), causing title to disappear

Tags: r, plot, roc

I'm trying to plot a ROC curve, with a numeric label for the optimal point and a title to the plot, however I keep getting

> "Error in rocit %>% plot() + text(1 - opt$Specificity, opt$Sensitivity,  :
> non-numeric argument to binary operator"

error message, causing my plot to miss it's title.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple and would appreciate any help, my code is as follows:

```
rocit %>% plot() + 
  text(1-opt$Specificity, opt$Sensitivity, paste('ponto de corte =', as.character(opt$Cutoff)),
                        pos = 3, offset = 1, font = 3)+
  title('Curva ROC para Eosinofilia Sérica X epos')
```

I've tried the code above, and checked class() for the two numeric arguments, they're numeric as expected. the plot comes out like this:
[image]

if i remove the text argument, I get the same error and a plot with a title but no text:
[image]

I have the following packages loaded:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nortest)
library(Hmisc)
library(verification)
library(ROCR)
library(ROCit)
```

and the opt vector is:

```
 Cutoff     Depth  Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity   F-Score   younden
1    230 0.7005348 0.7860963   0.7898089   0.7666667 0.8611111 0.5564756
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What packages do you have loaded?

Comment: Your code is using `ggplot` style addition of graphic elements (using `+`) but `text` and `title` are base plotting functions. That is, you are mixing the syntax of very different plotting frameworks. Since I don't know where the `plot` method for your object comes from (i.e. what package?) I do not know what the solution would be.

Comment: Idea 1, simply move `title()` before `test()`. idea two, inspect your text coordinates `paste(1-opt$Specificity, opt$Sensitivity)` they might not be what is expected

Comment: You are probably using `plot.rocci`, so I think you just want `plot(rocit)`, then on a newline, `title(......)`, and again on a newline, `text(.....)`. Don't chain the commands together using `+`.

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to answer individual questions but I included the packages I'm using, the rocit object comes from ROCit, and I've already inspected the coordinates, they're the expected values and numeric

Comment: Just remove the two `+`s.

Comment: " `-` is the 'binary operator' your error is referencing" https://stackoverflow.com/a/29665740/10276092 try this: `text(1 - opt[["Specificity"]], opt$Sensitivity, ...)...`